# DeltaSharing with CDF complains: cdf is not enabled on table - although reading with Delta lake works

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake, delta-sharing

SETUP:
Spark: 3.2.3
DeltaSharing Test-Server running locally

I am writing and reading data into a Deltalake with Spark.

Now I like to enable CDF for being able to read only the changes permanently with using DeltaSharing. DeltaSharing without CDF works.

The loaded packages:

```
conf.set('spark.sql.extensions','io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension')
conf.set('spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog','org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog')
```

Then I register the S3-path to a table:

```
spark.sql(f"CREATE TABLE if not exists retail USING DELTA LOCATION '{table_path}'")
spark.sql(f"ALTER TABLE retail SET TBLPROPERTIES(delta.enableChangeDataFeed = true)")
```

Then after creating new data in a DataFrame and I append this data to the deltalake file.

```
df.write.option("header", True).mode("append").format("delta").save(table_path))
```

When I read the data with a separate job directly from the delta lake it works:

```
table_path = f"s3a://{'BUCKET']}{s3folder}/retail"
df = (spark.read.format("delta")
          .option("readChangeFeed", "true")
          .option("startingVersion", "29")
          .load(table_path))
```

When using DeltaSharing it fails:

```
table_path = DS_PROFILE_FILE + '#' + 'PM.catalog.transactions'
df = (spark.read.format("deltaSharing")
          .option("readChangeFeed", "true")
          .option("startingVersion", "29")
          .load(table_path))
```

with:

: io.delta.sharing.spark.util.UnexpectedHttpStatus: HTTP request failed with status: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request {"errorCode":"INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE","message":"cdf is not enabled on table PM.catalog.transactions"}.

I am run out of ideas. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution in a
[delta.io blog](https://delta.io/blog/2022-10-10-delta-sharing-0-5-0-released/)

You need to tell the server configuration of delta-sharing as well that this table is CDF enabled:

```
shares:
- name: "PM"
  schemas:
  - name: "catalog"
    tables:
    - name: "transactions"
      location: "s3a://<bucket>/<path>/transactions"
      cdfEnabled: true
```